# Suddenly lost connection in jenkins(ubuntu 14) during implementing automation ui test

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, ui-automation

I built a new UI test framework with selenium/java/maven and then tried to deploy it in Jenkins with Ubuntu 1.4(AWS). After running the Jenkins job, it shows the following error.

NOTICE:

os: ubuntu 14.04 without desktop

jenkins: I need to setup headless mode with Xvfb plugin. 
chromedriver: headless chrome=73.0.3683.103
Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20

```
Failed
com.????global.products.testcase.TC003_products_MainPage_GGZ.checkCampMgmtPageExist (from TestSuite)

Error Message
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:19926
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-10-10-2-190', ip: '10.10.2.190', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-85-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Stacktrace
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:19926
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-10-10-2-190', ip: '10.10.2.190', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-85-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at com.automation.framework.base.DriverBase.findElement(DriverBase.java:74)
    at com.automation.framework.BasePage.element(BasePage.java:22)
    at .......
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. `Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:19926` are you sure with the path `localhost/127.0.0.1:19926`?

Comment: Are you sure that Selenium is running as you expect on the Jenkins server? CI servers are usually headless, and you have to take special care if you want full browsers available.

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:19926`

This one indicates that whatever you're trying to connect to is not available, it looks like Selenium is not running, make sure it's up and running and that the host and the port configurations are both correct.